# Grails 2.0 depedencies NoClassDefFound issue

Tags: grails, groovy, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror, buildconfig

I've got a problem with NoClassDefFound exception in Grails 2.0 when I tried to use library from external JAR.

I've checked that declared JARs are inside of created WAR, also grials dependecies-report do not marks any issues with that.

Locally added JARs or downloaded from Maven repo seems no difference. I've also tried to clean IVY cache and clean grails project without success.

Did you got any ideas how to fix it?

---

**BuildConfig.groovy** (part of)

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {

        compile (   "javax:activation:1.0",
                    "javax:mail:1.0",
                    "com.google.gdata:gdata-core:1.0",
                    "com.google.gdata:gdata-client:1.0",
                    "com.google.gdata:gdata-media:1.0",
                    "com.google.gdata:gdata-youtube:2.0"
        )

        runtime (   "javax:activation:1.0",
                    "javax:mail:1.0",
                    "com.google.gdata:gdata-core:1.0",
                    "com.google.gdata:gdata-client:1.0",
                    "com.google.gdata:gdata-media:1.0",
                    "com.google.gdata:gdata-youtube:2.0"
        )
    }

...

}
```

---

**LibraryController.groovy**

```
import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeService
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoEntry
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException

class LibraryController {

    private YouTubeService service
    private static final API_URL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"

    def index = {
        service = new YouTubeService("app")
    }
}
```

---

**Exception**

```
Class
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Message
    Could not initialize class com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeServiceClass
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Message
    Could not initialize class com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeService

Comment: I will usually just use 'jar -tf' to inspect the jar files inside the war file to make doubly sure that the class file YouTubeServiceClass is included.

Comment: When do you get this error? At runtime using `run-app`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using run-app and exception appears when entering library view.

Comment: I can't find javax:mail:1.0 in any of the repos. Sure its not javax.mail:mail?

Comment: Neither did I find the google jars in any of the repos. Are they manually installed to your local maven cache? Are the 4 custom maven repos used at all?

Comment: Mail and Activation JARs are from Google guide: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/java_client_lib.html#dependencies


Other dependecies are taken from Google gdata-java-client source package:
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list

Comment: Ok, so all jars are manually installed to local maven cache and resolved with mavenLocal()? Which means they probably don't have the correct metadata with regards to transitive dependencies. Sounds like you are missing one or more jars, like Burt said.

Comment: The Google guide states that you need mail.jar 1.4+, your version number is 1.0. I don't know if it's really version 1.0 or if that's just the version number you gave the jar when manually installing it. But rather than manually installing mail.jar, it would be easier to reference the latest one already in Maven Central: javax.mail:mail:1.4.5. Same goes for activation.jar: javax.activation:activation:1.1.1

Comment: The guide also says you need Ant 1.7+. Try adding  org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.3. Edit: Ant is probably only needed for building the gdata source, not when using the jars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` is not the same as `ClassNotFoundException`. Getting a `ClassNotFoundException` means the class isn't there, so you have a straightforward jar/dependency problem. `NoClassDefFoundError` means that the specified class was found, but that a class that it references wasn't found. It's a much more frustrating issue to track down because the JVM doesn't tell you what's missing.

You need to make sure that you have all of the dependencies of the class that's failing to load, and all of their dependencies, etc.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. After research I've discovered that com.google.common.collect.Maps was missing. Adding guava-libraries (http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) fixed that problem. 

But I've must downgrade guava to 10.0.1 because of compatibility issue:
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/issues/detail?id=180

Answer (score 0):

You have all your dependencies declared both in compile and runtime scope. Each dependency should be declared only once. If you declare a dependency in compile scope, it will also be available runtime. Since you need this class for compilation, you should keep com.google.gdata:gdata-youtube:2.0 under 'compile', and remove it from 'runtime'

A description of the available scopes, taken from the [user documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configurationsAndDependencies):

- build: Dependencies for the build system only
- compile: Dependencies for the compile step
- runtime: Dependencies needed at runtime but not for compilation (see above)
- test: Dependencies needed for testing but not at runtime (see above)
- provided: Dependencies needed at development time, but not during WAR deployment

Comment: I've left only 'compile' scope, but exception still appears.